# Why is OrderByDescending not working in linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a query that returns week ending in datetime format, I want to sort it  descending but seems that `OrderBy` is not working..

[image]

```
var WeekEnd = db.mqTimeReportingTimeLogs.OrderByDescending(e=>e.tlWeekEnding).Select(c => c.tlWeekEnding).Distinct().ToList();
```

I have also tried:

```
WeekEnd=WeekEnd.OrderByDescending(x=>x.tlWeekEnding).ToList();
```

but here x.tlWeekEnding does not appear.

Comment: It _could_ be the distinct throwing it off (although I don't think Distinct works this way in .NET) ... try doing that first and see what happens: `var WeekEnd = db.mqTimeReportingTimeLogs.Select(c => c.tlWeekEnding).Distinct().OrderByDescending(e=>e).ToList();`

Comment: What is the datatype of `tlWeekEnding`? From the screenshot it looks like it is a list of string. Which means it is sorted alphabetically not as dates.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I thought the same, but [the implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/8750960d3fafa46a9b838c351e995a01fa8b599f/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Distinct.cs) doesn't affect the ordering.

Comment: First do the DISTINCT then do the orderby ,like this 
var WeekEnd = db.mqTimeReportingTimeLogs.Distinct().OrderByDescending(e=>e.tlWeekEnding).Select(c => c.tlWeekEnding).ToList();

Comment: What is the backing data store for this? Could it be that the sort part of the query isn't getting translated into whatever query language the database uses?

Comment: no its datatype is 'datetime?' @Rahatur

Comment: It has to be something weird like that ... because it simply doesn't happen when using POCO's in a test environment. Either the underlying data store is returning the wrong data or there's more code around here that's causing it to fail (like some sort of weird equality comparer, or an `Equals` override or something)

Comment: @stack_user - to debug, first change your code to JUST return the descending order objects and debug it: `var WeekEnd = db.mqTimeReportingTimeLogs.OrderByDescending(e=>e.tlWeekEnding).ToList()` - debug this first, then update your question.

Comment: Yahh!!That worked @SimonWhitehead ..thanx

Comment: What does it mean that it does not work? Provide what the result looks like and how it should look If `tlWeekEnding` is `DateTime` then OrderByDescending(e=>e.tlWeekEnding.TimeOfDay) The rest of the code is correct and the order does not matter (as far as the result is concerned)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

var WeekEnd = db.mqTimeReportingTimeLogs.OrderByDescending(e=>e.tlWeekEnding);